# Converting <table> data to form scope with name & pair

Tags: coldfusion

I'm working on scraping a website. I have managed to get the contents of what I need, which is an HTML table like this:

```
<table id="warranty-information">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="ui-corner-top">Warranty Information</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Warranty</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">2 Years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="ui-corner-top">Hardware</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Adapter Style</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Cable Adapters</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Converter Type</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Cable Adapters</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Output Signal</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">DisplayPort</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to display the first `<TD>` of a `<TR> as a named input field whose value is the text inside the`` block.

I also want to display a second input field with value from 2nd `<TD>` block, but am lost as to how to do this.

Making use of a few functions from cflib like flattenSruct() and ConvertXMLtoStruct(), this is what I've tried so far:

```
<cfset regExp = REMatch('(?s)<div class="tab-pane" id="tchspcs".*?</div>',str)> 
<cfset regData = Replace(regExp[1],'<br> ','-','all')>
<cfset xhtm = Application.jtidy.makexHTMLValid(strToParse='#regData#')>
<cfset xhtml = Replace(xhtm,'<br />','-','all')>
<cfset getdataStructs = Application.ftSys.ConvertXmlToStruct(XMLParse(xhtml))>
<cfdump var="#xhtml#">
<cfset ApiData = getdataStructs.div.table.tr>

<table align="center" width="100%">
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(ApiData)#" index="i">
    <cfset data = Application.ftSys.flattenStruct(ApiData[i])>
    <cfloop collection="#data#" item="key">
    <cfoutput>
       <cfif key eq 'td'>
       <tr>
          <!---<cfif trim(data[key][1]) NEQ "">--->
          <cfdump var="#data[key]#">
          <td><input type="text" name="namespecification" id="namespecification" value="#data[key][1]#"></td>
          <!---</cfif>--->
          <td><textarea name="valuespecification" id="valuespecification" rows="5">#data[key][2]#</textarea></td>
          <!---#key#:#data[key]#--->
       </tr>
       </cfif>  
     </cfoutput>
    </cfloop> 
</cfloop>
</table>
```

I am looping through an array of structures, but a few of the arrays are empty and every array is coming as single entity like this combination of 2:

[image: First Image]
[image: single entity array]

Comment: If you dump getDataStructs, do you see what you hoped for?  What about dumping ApiData?

Comment: the following is the screenshot of the apidata dump http://prntscr.com/eyr69r

Comment: and this is the dump for getDataStructs - http://prntscr.com/eyr796

Comment: take a look at jSoup - it will allow you to use dom selectors on the html

Comment: Seconded re jSoup. And I'm gonna flag @DanBracuk for being obstructive. This is a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
results.fileContent = FileRead(ExpandPath("test.html"));

loadPaths = ArrayNew(1);
loadPaths[1] = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) & "cfcs/jar/jsoup-1.10.2.jar";

loaderObj = createObject("component", "cfcs.javaloader.JavaLoader").init(loadPaths);
jsoup = loaderObj.create("org.jsoup.Jsoup");

doc = jsoup.parse(results.fileContent);
table = doc.select("##warranty-information");
trs = table.select("tr");
for(i = 0; i < trs.size(); i++) {
    tds = trs.get(i).select("td");
    if( tds.size() ) {
        form[ tds.get(0).text() ] = tds.get(1).text();
    }
}

WriteDump(form);
```

This assumes your HTML is stored in an file (test.html) like this:

```
<table id="warranty-information">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="ui-corner-top">Warranty Information</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Warranty</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">2 Years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="ui-corner-top">Hardware</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Adapter Style</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Cable Adapters</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Converter Type</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Cable Adapters</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Output Signal</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">DisplayPort</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [jSoup](https://jsoup.org/) java library to achieve what you are after.  It will let you [parse your scraped html string](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string) and [then use DOM selectors](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) a la jQuery to navigate the html structure.

Selecting `tr td:first-child` should get you an array of the first `td` in each row.

Comment: Thanks @ryan: gotta Try it now

Comment: ok, i just download Jsoup and added this code `<cfscript>
loadPaths = ArrayNew(1);
loadPaths[1] = getdirectoryfrompath(getcurrenttemplatepath()) & "cfcs\jar\jsoup-1.10.2.jar";
loaderObj = createObject("component", "cfcs.javaloader.JavaLoader").init(loadPaths);
jsoup = loaderObj.create("org.jsoup.Jsoup"); 
//jsoup = CreateObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
HTMLDocument = jsoup.parse(results.fileContent);
TheDiv = HTMLDocument.select("##tchspcs");
writedump(TheDiv);
</cfscript>` and all it is showing me the dump http://prntscr.com/eyvdhy